# Resistor color code extrapolation

Tags: electrical-resistance

I can't help wondering: what should the color stripes be [on these](http://te-mpe-cp.web.cern.ch/te-mpe-cp/index.php?sub=goals)?

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is unfortunately not really about physics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know. But the silver band indicates a tolerance of ±10%.

Joke aside: The resistor is actually $225\, m\Omega$. (https://accelconf.web.cern.ch/accelconf/e00/PAPERS/THP1B09.pdf)